# Pronunciation differences between 어 and 오, 애 and 에 in DPRK

Tags: pronunciation, north-korean

Is there any difference in pronunciation between 어 and 오, 애 and 에 in DPRK? As I hear from news or documentary films, the announcer speech spells these vowels in different way. Anyway, is there any differences, for example, in Pyongyang everyday life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a different accent, but their pronunciations of those vowels are basically same. 
One notable thing is, a boundary of ㅐ and ㅔ has been blurred in both ROK and DPRK.